# Are there any Docker PHP images that don’t have the lengthy compile process, or how to reduce the amount of compilation, to speed up the image build?

Tags: php, image, docker, build, compilation

I am using one of the official Docker PHP images (7.1 Stretch) at https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/74b59e1cf7e5a356b5d4ee5eaeffe5f70f5ebd4c/7.1/stretch/cli/Dockerfile

Building this image (a full clean build) has a lengthy compilation process.  Is there any way to avoid or minimize this lengthy process?  For example, is there a PHP image that pulls binary packages rather than source code packages (which require compilation)?

Comment: Docker normally deals in binary images.  If you just use `php:7.1-cli-stretch` as an image name, it will pull a binary from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/).  It's always helpful to be able to rebuild images from source but for the "stock" images you usually don't need to.

Comment: Thanks for this input.  This was super helpful!